# make SVG document responsive with the viewbox based on aspect ratio

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js

I have created [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-svg-component-5ghbmw?file=/src/App.tsx) to illustrate the problem.

I have this [ResponsiveSVG](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-svg-component-5ghbmw?file=/src/components/ResponsiveSVG/ResponsiveSVG.tsx) component:

```
export function ResponsiveSVG({
  height,
  width,
  children,
  origin = { x: 0, y: 0 },
  preserveAspectRatio = "xMidYMid meet",
  innerRef,
  className,
  ...props
}: ResponsiveSVGProps): JSX.Element {
  const aspect = height === 0 ? 1 : width / height;

  const adjustedHeight = Math.ceil(width / aspect);

  return (
    <div
      data-testid="cutting-svg-container"
      style={{
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'visible',
        height: '1px',
      }}
    >
      <svg
        style={{ overflow: 'visible' }}
        className={className}
        preserveAspectRatio={preserveAspectRatio}
        width={width}
        height={adjustedHeight}
        viewBox={`${origin.x} ${origin.y} ${width} ${height}`}
        ref={innerRef}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would like my `ResponsiveSVG` component to know how to fit its content to the full width of the container while keeping the aspect ratio the same.

In the example I have a `circle` as a child of the svg document:

```
<ResponsiveSVG width={width} height={height}>
  <circle cx={width / 2} cy={height / 2} r={radius} />
</ResponsiveSVG>
```

On desktop, it looks like this:

[image]

But in mobile view, it looks like this:

[image]

My calculations make the `viewBox` width and height the same as the actual width and height I am passing in, so no change happens.

The viewBox coordinates are exactly the same as the viewport.

Comment: use a fixed size viewBox and fixed size contents within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the width and height of the containing element to the `viewBox` is actually the wrong direction. `viewBox` defines the canvas on which the svg content elements are drawn: if you draw a circle with `r="50"`, the viewBox width value must be at least 100, otherwise, it will never fit. If the center is at `cx=50`, the viewBox x value must not be greater than 0, otherwise the left side is cut off.

Responsiveness in SVG is achieved because there needs not to be any relation between the `viewBox` values and the `width` and `height` of the `<svg>` element. The canvas the child elements are drawn on is always fitted to the parent element dimensions.

In short, if all you want to achieve is to fit a circle in a `<svg>` element, choose a arbitrary radius `r`, set `cx=cy=r` and `viewBox="0 0 2r 2r"`, and it will work. There is no need to know anything explicit about the parent size.

If you want your `<svg>` element to be the width of the container, set it so: `width: 100%`. The default height is `auto`, so no need to write that or `preserveAspectRatio`. It will size itself such that the canvas defined by `viewBox` fits itself.

```html
    <div
      style="
        position: relative;
        overflow: visible;
        height: 1px;
      "
    >
      <svg
        style="
          width: 100%;
          overflow: visible;
        "
        viewBox="0 0 100 100"
      >
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want the circle to fit into the document.  Changing the width to 100%  does nothing to achieve this

Comment: you've also used width=100% in the style attribute which is invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry about the typo. As for the rest, that happens if you rely on code you do not show in your question. The problem is the way you compute the width and height props in your App.tsx file - add those lines to the question, and I can point out the errors.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.

It actually works perfectly if you resize the browser vertically.

I use a `ResizeObserver` to get the width and height from the parent element and I think that is good.

I think you are right though, the viewBox is not doing anything.  The values are the same

Comment: I hope my edit clears up that you are overthinking things. The "Scaleable" in "SVG" does everything you (seem to) need automatically.